# How to return values from inside subscribe in angular?

Tags: angular, return, subscribe

I have function that fetches data from api. I need to return the data to a variable declared inside the in class. Below is the the function

getColumns(){

```
      let auth_token='xkjhkdfdfdf';
      let url=this.api.apiList.contact_list;
      var columns={};
      this.common.getRequestTable(url,auth_token).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          columns=res.column_heading;
          return columns;
        })
  }
```

i have to pass the value to a variable declared in the class

```
columnList = {}
```

But when is try like

```
columnList=this.getColumns();
```

columnList is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Define your columns variable at class level :

```
let auth_token='xkjhkdfdfdf';
let url=this.api.apiList.contact_list;
var columns={};
```

// If your common is service where you are hitting your backend URL then try

```
getColumns() : Subscription {  
   return this.common.getRequestTable(url,auth_token).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          columns=res.column_heading;
          return columns;
        })
  }
```

Although this is not a right way to pass auth token like you are providing, and also a suggestion Please keep you variables name proper so that they themselves convey their use. If "common" is a service then please use "commonService".